# How to change the VMware Player version for a virtual machine?

Tags: vmware

I created a virtual machine with VMware Player v6.0.1, and I copied the vm to a server where it must run, but the player version there is v5.0.0,an when trying to run the VM is giving me the following error:

```
The configuration file "X:\MV_route\VM_name.vmx" was created by a VMware product that is incompatible with this version of VMware Player and cannot be used.

Cannot open the configuration file X:\MV_route\VM_name.vmx.
```

I can't upgrade the Player Version because I have vm's there already running, ad I would prefer no to create a new VM (I had spend a lot of time configuring the v6 VM).

Is there a way to configure the VM to run in VMware Player v5?

Comment: Looks like you don't have a [su] account. Research over there prior to posting a Question, as simply reposting the same thing is not encouraged.

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution there

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[image]

I faced the same issue, What i did was opened the vmx file/VMware Virtual machine configuration file in notepad++ and changed the value of the field "virtualHW.version" to that of the version number of workstaion in which you want to open it in.
scenario: I had VMWare Workstation 12 before then i switched to version 8.
and changed the 
virtualHW.version = 12 to 
virtualHW.version = 8.
and it worked flawlessly.
peace out! :-p

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @Rugved Mahamune answer

In addition, if you want to find which version you need to set

> virtualHw = "xx"

Just check image below:

[image]

credit: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1003746

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in https://superuser.com/questions/497001/vmware-player-downward-compatibility

It's simply to download VMware Vcenter Converter, witch is free, and change the version over there. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to convert anything.  Just open the vmx file and look/alter the version number to your current player.

Comment: This question was off topic and was answered on a different forum